# Who/What am I? A Riddle to my dear

Tags: riddle

*Dear,*

You like me, and I'm just like you 
 
We can't touch, but we can talk to 
 
We can't hear, but we can see through 
 
I'm always there and you come more than once 
 
'Cause once is not enough for our love 
 
Time is passing, but tonight again 
 
When you laugh at me, I laugh at you, my charm 
    *Pls don't afraid to see me, when the dark has come.*

*Beloved, :P*

Comment: The answer could be a "Dream". But hard to justify all the lines. 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is that

> Our Mirror Image?

You like me, and I'm just like you

> We like to see in mirror, and mirror image of us is same as like us.

We can't touch, but we can talk to

> Actually we can not touch mirror image.

We can't hear, but we can see through

> We both can not hear each other but we can see.

I'm always there and you come more than once
'Cause once is not enough for our love

> Frequently we go in front of it, Once is not enough

Time is passing, but tonight again

> not sure about this line.

When you laugh at me, I laugh at you, my charm

> If we laugh our mirror image also laugh

Pls don't afraid to see me, when the dark has come.

> It's horrible to face yourself into mirror at dark.

Comment: Yes that's it. Congrats you got the right answer. "Time is passing, but tonight again => not sure about this line." Yep, that line just added to make the riddle sounds dreamy. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of like this that shows itself at night is

> My shadow

Here's more:

> Our image is a likeness of ourselves 
>  We can't hear each other, but I can see my shadow 
>  We arrive at our shadow when it is dark and a light brings it to life 
>  At night is when we see our shadow most. In fact, it has been said that one can be afraid of one's own shadow. 
>  The title indicates that a what is possible and if a what is possible, then that tells me the need to say so makes it likely, so I am thinking it must be a thing, not a person, which shadow fits.

Comment: A nice answer for me. After I read my riddle again, shadow could be the answer too. But just bcos I was thinking "Mirror" when making this, shadow is not marked as right. However, thank you for the answer.